# Best way to clean loafers?

Tags: cleaning, shoes

My loafers (blue) have some velvet stuff on them. If I clean them with a cloth soaked in water then it turns them black in some areas which really makes them look ugly.

Even when I wash them, they attain a uneven colour. What is the best and easiest way to clean them?

```
**UPDATE**
```

The material is same as:

[image]

Comment: In what areas do they turn black? The areas with velvet?

Comment: @Wipqozn yeah, the whole shoe has same stuff.Not velvet, actually something like that which are common on loafers .

Comment: I don't think this question can really be answered unless we know what material is on the slippers.

Comment: @Wipqozn updated.

Answer (score 3):

Wash stained loafers with mild dish detergent mixed with water. Using a soft toothbrush, scoop up a small amount of suds and apply them to the stain, keeping the shoes as dry as possible. Gently scrub the mark with the toothbrush and let the mixture sit for a few minutes before wiping it away. If any stain remains, repeat the process.